# Is it possible to retrieve status of a video content (till he/she plays) onclick exit button in the video using react native webview

Tags: react-native

The video content developed has an option of recording the status until where the content has been watched and is still in Progress or completed watching.The status gets recorded on clicking the exit button in video with the help of scorm in general web application.

My Question here is, I have placed the video content in my app and want to retrieve the status of the video from react-native app.

Can somebody help me out in figuring out the problem.

Thank you